# check column values in php not working

Tags: php

I want to take the print of students reports with following PHP code. **(the 4th column is Marks).** I am unable to modify the code. Can any body help me . And i need the reports where the marks is more than 75. in this regard?

```
<?php
    $row = 1;
    if(($handle = fopen("xyz.csv", "r")) !== false) {
        $table1  = '<table div id="kk">';
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
            $table1Add =  false;
            if($row >=1 && $row <= 53)
                $table1Add = true;
                    $num = count($data);
            if($row == 1) {
                $table1 .= '<thead><tr>';
                for($c = 0; $c <= 8; $c++) {
                    $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "&nbsp;" : $data[$c];
                    $table1 .= '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
                }
                $table1 .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
               } else {
              if($table1Add) $table1 .= '<tr>';           
                for($c = 0; $c <= 8; $c++) {
                    $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "&nbsp;" : $data[$c];
                    if($table1Add) $table1 .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
                }
                if($table1Add) $table1 .= '</tr>';
                }
            $row++;
        }
        $table1 .= '</tbody></table>';
        fclose($handle);
        echo $table1;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: So your table has 9 columns and you want to check if the `marks` in the `4th column` is greater than `75`, if yes only then print that row, correct?

Comment: yes mr. Cheezburger.  Then only the rows having marks more than 75 to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
    $row = 1;
    if(($handle = fopen("xyz.csv", "r")) !== false) {
        $table1  = '<table div id="kk">';
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
            $table1Add =  false;
            if($row >=1 && $row <= 53)
                $table1Add = true;
                    $num = count($data);
            if($row == 1) {
                $table1 .= '<thead><tr>';
                for($c = 0; $c <= 8; $c++) {
                    $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "&nbsp;" : $data[$c];
                    $table1 .= '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
                }
                $table1 .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
               } else {
              if($table1Add) $table1 .= '<tr>';  
                /* this bit edited */
                $temp_holder = ''; 
                $flag = false;         
                for($c = 0; $c <= 8; $c++) {
                    if($c==3 && $data[$c]>75) { $flag = true; } 
                    if($table1Add){
                        $temp_holder .= '<td>'.(empty($data[$c]) ? "&nbsp;" : $data[$c]).'</td>';
                    }
                    if($c==8 && flag==true) { $table1 .= $temp_holder; }
                    /* till here */
                }
                if($table1Add) $table1 .= '</tr>';
                }
            $row++;
        }
        $table1 .= '</tbody></table>';
        fclose($handle);
        echo $table1;
        }
    ?>
```

What's done above is, we will use a temp variable to keep all the `<td>` data, when you reach the 4th column (which is 3 starting from 0), check if the marks is greater than 75, if yes, set the `flag` to true. If the `flag` is true, that means that row has marks greater than 75, so append all the `<td>` values from the temp variable to the `table1` variable.

Comment: it coming entire results where the marks are above 75 and and below 75.   the string checking is not working.

Comment: @Mohan Can you edit this line and see what you get: `if($c==3 && $data[$c]>75) { var_dump($data[$c]); $flag = true; }`

Comment: After editing the code only, i got the rows where the marks are below and above 75. I. think some other sting to be incorporated.

Comment: @Mohan, you might need to check which is the actual column with the `marks` and change this `$c==3` accordingly. What did the `var_dump($data[$c]);` print?

Comment: @Cheezburger, could you simply the code? What I want is the table to be printed where the marks should be more than 75.

Comment: @Mohan, can you paste one row of the table data that you see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49649/discussion-between-mohan-and-i-can-has-cheezburger)